How to debug Android Auto app on a real device
My problem is that my Android Auto app behaves differntly on the Desktop Head Unit (Android Auto emulator) and on the real Android Auto device.
I have read this page of documentation, which says that my kind of app (navigation) is not possible to launch on Android Auto without going through google play, but I really need a way to debug the Android Auto app on the real device.
Finally the question: Is there really no way to debug Android Auto app on the real device?
My device is a media tablet with Android Auto and Apple Car Play along with radio, usb-flash playback, etc.

There are physical devices (head units) that you can buy and use. But as you've said you'd need to go through Google Play.
So I'd suggest using different versions of emulator DHUs before buying a physical one, if you haven't already. You can use the config folder to select different variants of DHUs, for example:
./desktop-head-unit -c config/default_720p.ini

If you can point out specifically what kind of debugging issue you are having, it might help.

It's not possible to debug android app from real device but if you want to check how you app will behave after updating to google play store you can upload your APK/AAB to internal app sharing and test app in real device without updating to google play store.
https://play.google.com/console/u/0/internal-app-sharing/
